# How can I bind this items to database?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is my combobox that bind to database.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUnitType" runat="server" CssClass="fonttah" 
          DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="UnitTypeName" 
             DataValueField="UnitTypeID">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SellAutomationConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [UnitTypeID], [UnitTypeName] FROM [UnitTypes]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now I replacing it with below code ( using a jquery plugin to show combo box that have a avatar with items).

```
 <table>
        <tr>
           <td width="208">
                            <div id="languages">
                                <ul>
                                   <li>&nbsp;<img src="../../App_Themes/DefaultTheme/images/Select.png" alt="SelectItems" border="0" align="absmiddle"/>&nbsp;<span style=" font-weight:bold">... انتخاب کنید</span>
                                   </li>
                                    <li>&nbsp;<img src="../../App_Themes/DefaultTheme/images/home.png" alt="Home" align="absmiddle" border="0"/>&nbsp;<span style="text-align:left">واحدهای اقامتی کوتاه مرتبه</span>
                                   </li>
                                   <li>&nbsp;<img src="../../App_Themes/DefaultTheme/images/shopping.png" alt="shopping" align="absmiddle" border="0"/>&nbsp;<span>واحدهای تجاری</span>
                                   </li>
                               </ul>
                            </div>
            </td>
       </tr>
 </table>
```

And now I want to read data from database.In fact using this code instead of that combo box. How can I bind it to database?
Thanks.

Comment: What part do you want coming from the database? By what are you replacing the select(DropDownList)? Your question is quite unclear to give a proper answer. Also, remove the `asp-classic` tag. You are using `asp.net`

Comment: Probably looking for a <asp:GridView /> control

Comment: @nunespascal ok.I remove that tag.Dropdown's items come from DB.
and now I use dropdown list that design with table and jquery.
now I want give that items from DB.but how?

Comment: @codingbiz No,that's not my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asp.net has a lot of [databound controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), many that will allow you do some custom formatting to display your data.

Since you have a list of data to show, consider using the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server" id="table1" >
      <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server">
      <td runat="server">
        <%-- Data-bound content. --%>
        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach to populate combobox....

```
string strcombobox="<table><tr><td width="208"><div id="languages">
                             <ul>##ListString##</ul>
                             </div></td></tr></table>";


DataSet ds=Get Data To Be Filled from Database;

string strListCollection=string.Empty;

for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
{
 string liCode="<li>&nbsp;<img src="##imageSource##" alt="##imageAlt##" border="0" align="absmiddle"/>&nbsp;<span style=" font-weight:bold">##ListValue##</span> </li> ";
 liCode=liCode.Replace("##imageSource##",ds.Table[0].Rows[i]["iamgeSource"].ToString());
 liCode=liCode.Replace("##imageAlt##",ds.Table[0].Rows[i]["imageAlt"].ToString());
 liCode=liCode.Replace("##ListValue##",ds.Table[0].Rows[i]["ListValue"].ToString());
 strListCollection+=liCode;
}

strcombobox=strcombobox.Replace("##ListString##",strListCollection);
divWhereComboBoxCome.innerHtml=strcombobox;
```